# Leave some silence prior to trimming at audio events using sox

Tags: wav, trim, sox

I have some audio files that look like this:

[image]

I wanted to know if it is possible to delay the trimming process by a specified amount, for example 0.1s, prior to trimming the audio at the end of each silence sections?

The `sox` command that I use to trim at the end of each silence section is:

```
for %%i in ("*.wav") do "%_sox%" -V3 "%%~fi" "SilenceTrimBegin-1secclips\%%~ni.wav" silence 1 0.0 -40d trim 0 1 : newfile : restart
```

Can you assist me in basically leaving some silence before the active audio event?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "pad 0.5 0.5" at the end of the sox recording command to prevent too strict clipping.